# How to compare the items in list with the user input?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to compare the answer from user with a list:

```
answers=["Sundar Pichai","Mark Zukenberg","Narendra Modi"]
print ('Welcome to Quizz!!')
player_name= raw_input("Enter Your Name:")
def out_ans():
    guess_ans = raw_input("enter your answer:")    
    for ans in answers:
        if guess_ans.lower() == ans.lower():
            print(player_name  +" correct answer")

        else:
            print(player_name + " its a wrong answer")
print ("Q.No 1 Who is the present CEO of Google??")             
out_ans()
print ("Q.No 2 Who is the founder of FaceBook??")
out_ans()
```

This is the output

```
Welcome to Quizz!!

Enter Your Name: xyz
Q.No 1 Who is the present CEO of Google??
enter your answer: sundar pichai
xyz its a correct answer
xyz its a wrong answer
xyz its a wrong answer
Q.No 2 Who is the founder of FaceBook??
enter your answer: mark zukenberg
xyz its a wrong answer
xyz its a correct answer
xyz its a wrong answer
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your code?

Comment: is the issue the 3 outputs instead of one? You might consider having a flag `right=False` that is set to True if they get it right and only print after the for loops

Comment: You could also add a `break` statement after the if condition.

Comment: Or... use a dict for he answer + question combo if the value doesn't match the value for that key (question) t's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answers=["Sundar Pichai","Mark Zukenberg","Narendra Modi"]
print ('Welcome to Quizz!!')
player_name= raw_input("Enter Your Name:")

def out_ans():
    guess_ans = raw_input("enter your answer:")
    if guess_and.lower() in [x.lower() for x in answers]:
        print(player_name  +" correct answer")
    else:
        print(player_name + " its a wrong answer")


print ("Q.No 1 Who is the present CEO of Google??")             
out_ans()
print ("Q.No 2 Who is the founder of FaceBook??")
out_ans()
```

But what do you think will happen when I answer on first question 'Mark Zukenberg'? :) Yes, you are right - program will say it is correct answer. To avoid situations like this, change architecture of your quiz as well:

```
def check_ans(player_ans, valid_answer):
    result = "correct answer" if player_ans.lower() == valid_answer.lower() else "its a wrong answer"
    return '{0} {1}'.format(player_name, result)

quiz = (("Q.No 1 Who is the present CEO of Google??", "Sundar Pichai"),
        ("Q.No 2 Who is the founder of FaceBook??", "Mark Zukenberg"))

print('Welcome to Quizz!!')
player_name = input("Enter Your Name:")

for question, answer in quiz:
    player_ans = input(question)
    print(check_ans(player_ans, answer))
```

Comment: return '{0} {1}'.format(player_name, result) what is the need of '{0} {1}' these ??

Comment: It is caused by format function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). I think this is better approach than concatenating strings like: `player_name + ' ' + result`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to print the message only once, informing the user about the correctness of his answer.

Then you need something like this:

```
def out_ans():
    guess_ans = raw_input("enter your answer:")
    correct = False
    for ans in answers:
        if guess_ans.lower() == ans.lower():
            correct = True
    if correct:
        print(player_name  +" correct answer")
    else:
        print(player_name + " its a wrong answer")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to print everytime, when you find your response, return :

```
def out_ans():
    guess_ans = raw_input("enter your answer:")    
    for ans in answers:
        if guess_ans.lower() == ans.lower():
            #if we find a correct answer, exit
            print(player_name  +" correct answer")
            return 
    #if didn't find any correct answer 
    print(player_name + " its a wrong answer")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
answers=[ "Sundar Pichai", "Mark Zukenberg", "Narendra Modi" ]
flagGuessWrong = False
print ( 'Welcome to Quizz!!' )

player_name = raw_input( "Enter Your Name:" )


def out_ans():
  guess_ans = raw_input( "enter your answer:" )    
  for ans in answers:
    if guess_ans.upper() == ans.upper():
      print(player_name  +" correct answer")
      flagGuessWrong = False
      break
    else:
      flagGuessWrong = True

  if(flagGuessWrong):
      print(player_name + " its a wrong answer")


print ("Q.No 1 Who is the present CEO of Google??")             
out_ans()
print ("Q.No 2 Who is the founder of FaceBook??")
out_ans()
```

This way it will compare everything you have on the array, but keep in mind it will not give you the correct answer (Eg: Q.No 2 Who is the founder of FaceBook?? => Narendra Modi (Will give correct) ) this is because you are looping through the entire array and once it finds a matching pair it will leave (My modification). The rest you need to apply some logic, maybe a dictionary so that he will find key/value pairs and return the correct answer.